# converting a string form object saved with data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I convert a string form object saved with data() using JavaScript (or jQuery)?

e.g: Convert this:

```
Object {imageNum: 0, text: "'sth1','sth2','sth3'"}
```

into this:

```
Object {imageNum: 0, text: ['sth1','sth2','sth3']}
```

or just remove the quotes so as when calling $("#data-store").data()["text"] I will get ['sth1','sth2','sth3'] or 'sth1','sth2','sth3'

What I am trying to do is to load the fonts which are stored in #data-store", but to set the fonts for google I need format like that:

```
WebFontConfig = {
  google: { families: [ 'Aclonica', 'Acme', 'Alegreya' ]
    }
  };
```

here is my buggy JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fonts-container ul li', function(){ 
  var $el = $(this);
  var fontName = $el.data('fontname');
  $(this).closest(".editor").find('.text2').css('font-family', fontName);

    parent.$("#data-store").data()["text"] = $(this).css('font-family');
    var dataobject = $("#data-store").data();
    dataobject.text = dataobject.text.split(",");
    WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families:  [dataobject.text ]  
    }
  }
    fontLoad();   
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var text= $("#data-store").data('text'); //{imageNum: 0, text: "'sth1','sth2','sth3'"};
text = text.replace(/'/g, "").split(/,/)
```

Comment: I am getting error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'split'

Comment: @lipenco From the shared `text: "'sth1','sth2','sth3'"` value I was assuming it was a string... now it looks like `text` is an array... can you try `console.log(JSON.stringify($("#data-store").data('text')))` before the above code is executed

Comment: I am getting  "'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif" form console

Answer (score 0):

You can convert text (which is a string) into an array using the javascript split method.

So,

```
var myobj =  {imageNum: 0, text: "'sth1','sth2','sth3'"};
myobj.text = myobj.text.split(",");
```